# How to compare list elements and keep duplicates?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, purrr

I have a big list of redditors

```
str(list_map_descr)
List of 4570
 $ Europa_Teles_BTR    :'data.frame':   1916 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ subreddit: chr [1:1916] "portugal" "Warthunder" "Warthunder" "portugal" ...
  ..$ date_utc : chr [1:1916] "2020-05-30" "2020-05-30" "2020-05-30" "2020-05-30" ...
 $ growmylife          :'data.frame':   92 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ subreddit: chr [1:92] "PsoriaticArthritis" "Telegram" "google" "Notion" ...
  ..$ date_utc : chr [1:92] "2021-06-27" "2021-01-04" "2020-12-14" "2020-10-01" ...
 $ fzncdata            :'data.frame':   182 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ subreddit: chr [1:182] "a:t5_39x4c" "nba" "NEET" "NEET" ...
  ..$ date_utc : chr [1:182] "2019-06-21" "2019-06-11" "2019-06-09" "2019-04-30" ...
```

and a transformed, filtered version of this list for my analysis.

```
str(list_map_date_o_2_1)
List of 2132
 $ Europa_Teles_BTR    :'data.frame':   562 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ subreddit : chr [1:562] "Warthunder" "Warthunder" "Warthunder" "Warthunder" ...
  ..$ date_utc  : Date[1:562], format: "2020-05-30" "2020-05-30" "2020-05-29" ...
  ..$ Posts_stop: num [1:562] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Posts_game: num [1:562] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ growmylife          :'data.frame':   37 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ subreddit : chr [1:37] "RocketLeague" "DaysGone" "StopGaming" "StopGaming" ...
  ..$ date_utc  : Date[1:37], format: "2020-09-23" "2020-04-04" "2019-10-10" ...
  ..$ Posts_stop: num [1:37] NA NA 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ Posts_game: num [1:37] 1 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ fzncdata            :'data.frame':   15 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ subreddit : chr [1:15] "DotA2" "GlobalOffensive" "DotA2" "DotA2" ...
  ..$ date_utc  : Date[1:15], format: "2019-03-30" "2019-03-02" "2018-11-28" ...
  ..$ Posts_stop: num [1:15] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Posts_game: num [1:15] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I want to filter now my old list `list_map_descr` by the elements of the new list `list_map_date_o_2_1`.

I thought it could be tricky that the lists share their element names, but have different variables in their data frames, so first I extracted only the names of the elements

```
words <- as.list(names(list_map_date_o_2_1))
```

and then I tried all versions of filter, keep, lapply that I could imagine e.g.

```
list_map_descr_test_3 <- map(list_map_descr, ~filter(words %in% .x))
list_map_descr_test_2 <- map(list_map_descr, ~ filter(.x, .x %in% words))
list_map_descr_test_2 <- map(list_map_descr, ~ keep(any(.x %in% words == TRUE)))
list_map_descr_test_2 <- mapply(function(x, y) x %in% y, list_map_descr, words, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
list_map_descr_test_2 <- lapply(function(x, y) x %in% y, list_map_descr, words, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
list_map_descr_test_2 <- purrr::keep(list_map_descr, ~.x %in% words == TRUE)
```

None of this worked. I think the problem is that I am not trying to filter by a value, instead I want to tell R to compare both element names and this I can not implement with my approaches.

I would expect this:

```
str(list_map_descr_test_3)
List of 2132
 $ Europa_Teles_BTR    :'data.frame':   1916 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ subreddit: chr [1:1916] "portugal" "Warthunder" "Warthunder" "portugal" ...
  ..$ date_utc : chr [1:1916] "2020-05-30" "2020-05-30" "2020-05-30" "2020-05-30" ...
 $ growmylife          :'data.frame':   92 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ subreddit: chr [1:92] "PsoriaticArthritis" "Telegram" "google" "Notion" ...
  ..$ date_utc : chr [1:92] "2021-06-27" "2021-01-04" "2020-12-14" "2020-10-01" ...
 $ fzncdata            :'data.frame':   182 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ subreddit: chr [1:182] "a:t5_39x4c" "nba" "NEET" "NEET" ...
  ..$ date_utc : chr [1:182] "2019-06-21" "2019-06-11" "2019-06-09" "2019-04-30" ...
```

I am very grateful for any suggestion!

Comment: It looks like you just want `list_map_descr[names(list_map_date_o_2_1)]`? If not, please include a fully [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/17303805), including example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
nm1 <- intersect(names(list_map_descr), names(list_map_date_o_2_1))
list_map_new <- list_map_descr[nm1]
```